# sdkman installation fails on raspberry pi

Tags: bash, java, raspberry-pi, jdk

I am trying to use SDKMAN to install java 17 on raspberry pi and the installation seems to work at first, it makes an initial download, but then it intends to `Installing script cli archive...` and it fails at the download portion of that step (see log below). Any help is greatly appreciated!! Sorry if I'm missing information, I'm a noob with this :)

```
Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN...
Looking for unzip...
Looking for zip...
Looking for curl...
Looking for sed...
Installing SDKMAN scripts...
Create distribution directories...
Getting available candidates...
Prime platform file...
Prime the config file...
Installing script cli archive...
* Downloading...
######################################################################## 100.0%
* Checking archive integrity...
* Extracting archive...
* Copying archive contents...
* Cleaning up...

Installing script cli archive...
* Downloading...
#=#=#
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
'curl --fail --location --progress-bar "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/broker/download/native/install/${SDKMAN_NATIVE_VERSION}/${SDKMAN_PLATFORM}" > "$sdkman_zip_file"': command failed with exit code 22.
```

Comment: Being able to look at the original script would be useful - its not finding something its looking for - and I'd hazard that its building a URL to a file that's not actually there. - could you share a link to SDKMAN?

Comment: Also - is it a 32 or 64 bit raspberry pi install? A quick look at the Oracle website suggests there's no 32 bit installer. The older pi I have is 32 bit, and if yours is running a 32 bit OS, that might be the source of the problem

Comment: Uh oh, I think you hit the problem :(. For reference, these are the install instructions of sdkman: https://sdkman.io/install. I would have shared the installer script itself, but I don't know which one it is or how to get it.
But yeah, looking at the result of uname command, it is indeed a 32bit device. So, like you said, that may be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

This indicates that the file isn't there. There's not much that can be done at the end user version, though its worth thinking about why SDKMAN is trying to download a non existent file

I'd make a few 'informed' guesses here.

While newer Raspberry Pi systems are 64 bit capable, the 'standard' Raspberry Pi OS is 32 bit as of 2023. There *is* a 'beta' 64 bit raspberry pi OS build however.

Looking at oracle's site - specifically the one that hosts scripting friendly links to [java versions](https://www.oracle.com/sg/java/technologies/downloads/#java17). They have only 64 bit arm and x86 versions. I'd guess your script isn't really checking 'properly' for 32 bit arm versions and rejecting, and building a non existent link

There's a few options here. With a newer raspberry PI - you could try a 64 bit
OS and see if SDKman would work there, since there's a valid java version.

Less noob friendly would be finding a 32 bit/arm compatible build of that version of java and either installing it yourself or modifying SDKman to do it.

On that note - according to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/r677q9/installing_java_17_on_pi_4/) temurin's build of java has arm32 support - and that's supported on [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/jdks#tem). This might be the simplest approach, if you're willing to switch java builds.

In this case, the lack of proper error checking also feels like a bug, and it might be worth raising a ticket about it with the SDKMAN devs,

Comment: Thanks for finding that reddit post! I need it to be java 17 or newer for my application, so I'll give that a try. Thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: hey it did work!! thanks again :D I followed the instructions on the reddit post and the list of commands from one of the comments of the reddit post to install the version proposed in the post. Here is the link with the list of commands to install for anyone that needs it for reference in the future:  https://gist.github.com/filipelenfers/ef3f593deb0751944bb54b744bcac074 
keep in mind that you'll need to modify the folders and filenames according to your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue, and I think JourneyMan geek has the right of it. I'm fleshing out a new Pironman case install, and can confirm that Raspbian ARM64 is buggy, at least as far as the desktop goes. I'm willing to wait until they get the ARM64 sorted for now, but as of today, SDKMAN will not successfully install on Raspbian 32. The SDKMAN installer looks at `uname -s` and `uname -m` to decide which SDKMAN binaries to download. (I could have sworn that SDKMAN used to be purely shell-script driven, but apparently the clever boys have been experimenting with "improving" things with golang and rustlang, meaning if you don't get the right binaries for your platform it's not gonna work.

So far as I've been able to tell, they don't publish what versions of the binaries are available on the server, and I know for a fact the installer script doesn't enumerate them completely. So far I haven't be able to guess the right version, and the SDKMAN Slack channels have been mostly dead when I visit them.

(I suppose I'm late to the game of complaining about having lost all my reputation and needing to start over with the reorg after the superuser takeover, but it stinks. I hadn't been posting here very often anyway.)

Truth is, RasPi is an edge case, and most industrial Linux use of SDKMAN seems pretty stable.

Oh, well. If I ever figure it out I'll try to remember to update this.

Comment: Ah, it *is* a beta - just for the sake of completeness - does it work on that at all?The only PI I have is... the old model, and honestly its too slow for a GUI install without losing what little hair I have left. There's been no super user takeover - and if you had an old account, and got info, you can try reclaiming it by using the contact link and getting staff to take a look.

Comment: Old account isn't worth my time to pursue. Convo generated on my work Slack tells me co-workers are running the 64 bit with no issues, and with RasPi 5 just announced requiring a new Raspian that ships in October they'll need that to be working well; I'll try again then.